# How to get cell coordinates of a shape in an Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, shapes, win32com

I am trying to extract some records from an excel file. They look like shown here.
[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqvDk.png)

The arrow in **Row 5** is an inserted **shape**, that indicates that text in E5 is to be used for cells that the arrow covers (in the image, F5 to I5).

So, I need to extract the cell coordinates of arrow start and end, using Python.

I have tried using win32com dispatch, but using that I can get only TopLeftCell address. I also need address for right end.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this 2 days later I posted the question.

Using win32com dispatch, we can obtain TopLeftCell, as well as the height and width of shape. Comparing the sum of x-coord of TopLeftCell and width of shape to the sum of x-coord of every cell in the row, the right end of shape can be obtained.